# Переодически падает Web сервер

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть VPS сервер Ubutnu 18.04 на котором размещён сайт (php7.2, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin). Проблема заключается в том, что каждый день в 00:00 по МСК (сервера тоже в МСК) сайт падает, начинает долго грузить, а потом и вовсе выдает ошибку "502 bad gateway nginx". Установил php7.2-fpm. Проблема не ушла. По графикам хостинга, нагрузка маленькая (в лимиты и даже близко к лимитам vps не грузиться). На днях выполнил команду php7.2-fpm reload и сайт проработал 2 дня без падений, упал, встал и ещё 2 дня работал. Позовчера сайт падал каждые 5-7 минут. Самое интересное, что в /var/log/apache2/access.log в периоды падение есть записи об успешных подключениях, а в /var/log/apache2/error.log записи за период падения отсутствуют. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Если у вас падает fpm, значит и читать нужно не логи апача, а логи fpm

Comment: Посмотрел лог: [01-Mar-2022 12:16:06] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it, но сайт упал через 2 минуты